# Webscraping dynamic tables for flight information

Tags: python, php, web-scraping, dynamic, qnetworkrequest

I have a question about webscraping. I need to scrape a dynamic website whereby there are multiple airpline trips on different dates. what is important for me is the group composition per flighing date. The group composition is hidden in a pop up whereby when you press the link there is no seperated link.

How can is scrape this type of a website. i heard a lot of times analyze the network requests that are being made. Did that I understand what is happening but i don't really know how to translate that to a scraping code in php/python. If you have knowledge in this field I would appriciate it if you could help me.

Thanks in advance

I already did write some code but it seems to be quite a task to transform the steps that I make into python / php code. I need a step-by-step plan on how to create a script.

Comment: The website i try to scrape. https://www.sawadee.nl/groepsrondreizen/midden-en-zuid-amerika/costa-rica/crs-ongerept-regenwoud-en-vulkanen/vertrekdata-en-prijzen/

Comment: Do you have the permission from this website to scrape their data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.